# create tutorial mode

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have a **Qt** application and want to show a little tutorial when the user access the application for the first time. Something like this:

[image]

How can I do something like this on Qt?

I'm using Qt 5.4 on Windows.

Comment: Add QLabel as child of the central widget, so that it fills the entire widget and is on top (you probably don't want to to put it into the layout, but manually set it's height and width to fill the area). Place a semi-transparent image into the label, which shows what you want. You can draw the image in code or draw it separately and load it from disk/resources. Or instead of QLabel, use a custom QWidget with paintEvent drawing what you want, semi-transparently as needed.

Comment: If you want to grey out the screen, you can use a [semi-transparent popup](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-popup.html).  Not exactly sure how you'd make that circle fully transparent.  However, you could also just draw a red circle or animated, eye-catching text above the button as hyde was saying.

Comment: Return and Next are buttons?

Comment: @eyllanesc it can be buttons or any other way to go to the next tutorial 'page'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To perform this task we must make the translucent background, we do it by activating the attribute `Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground`, then we use QPainterPath to draw the rectangle minus the transparent circle.

Then use eventFilter to know some events like when they are displayed, if you change the size or position.

Then a structure is created to store the data, in this case the center of the circle, the radius, the position of the text and the text itself.

Then the next and return buttons are added, and the logic of the page change is handled in the slot.

**tutowidget.h**

```
#ifndef TUTOWIDGET_H
#define TUTOWIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
class QButtonGroup;

class TutoWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    struct Pages{
        QPoint center;
        int radius;
        QPoint  pText;
        QString text;
    };
public:
    TutoWidget(QWidget *parent);
    void addPage(const QPoint &center, int radius, const QPoint &pText, const QString & text);
    bool eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event);
protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *);
private slots:
    void onClicked(int id);
private:
    QWidget *mParent;
    QButtonGroup *group;
    QVector<Pages> pages;
    int currentIndex = -1;
};

#endif // TUTOWIDGET_H
```

**tutowidget.cpp**

```
#include "tutowidget.h"

#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QButtonGroup>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QEvent>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QPainter>

TutoWidget::TutoWidget(QWidget *parent):QWidget(0)
{
    setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint|Qt::Popup);
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground, true);
    mParent = parent;
    mParent->installEventFilter(this);

    QVBoxLayout *vlay = new QVBoxLayout(this);
    vlay->addItem(new QSpacerItem(20, 243, QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Expanding));
    QHBoxLayout *hlay = new QHBoxLayout;
    vlay->addLayout(hlay);
    group = new QButtonGroup(this);
    const QStringList nameBtns{"Return", "Next"};
    for(int i=0; i < nameBtns.length(); i++){
        QPushButton* btn = new QPushButton(nameBtns[i]);
        btn->setFlat(true);
        group->addButton(btn, i);
        hlay->addWidget(btn);
    }
    connect(group, static_cast<void (QButtonGroup::*)(int)>(&QButtonGroup::buttonClicked),
            this, static_cast<void (TutoWidget::*)(int)>(&TutoWidget::onClicked));
    hlay->addItem(new QSpacerItem(40, 20, QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Minimum));
    group->button(0)->hide();
}

void TutoWidget::addPage(const QPoint &center, int radius, const QPoint &pText, const QString &text)
{
    pages << Pages{center, radius, pText, text};
    if(currentIndex == -1){
        currentIndex = 0;
        update();
    }
}

bool TutoWidget::eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event){
    if(watched == mParent){

        switch (event->type()) {
        case QEvent::Show:
            QTimer::singleShot(10,  this, &QWidget::show);
            break;
        case QEvent::Close:
            close();
            break;
        case QEvent::Move:
            move(mParent->mapToGlobal(QPoint(0, 0)));
            break;
        case QEvent::Resize:
            resize(mParent->size());
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    return QWidget::eventFilter(watched, event);
}

void TutoWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *){
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setPen(Qt::NoPen);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    painter.setBrush(QColor(100, 100, 100, 200));
    QPainterPath path;
    if(currentIndex != -1){
        QPoint center = pages[currentIndex].center;
        int radius = pages[currentIndex].radius;
        QString text = pages[currentIndex].text;
        QPoint pText = pages[currentIndex].pText;
        path.moveTo(center + radius/2*QPoint(1, 0));
        path.arcTo(QRect(center-radius/2*QPoint(1, 1),radius*QSize(1, 1)), 0, 360);
        path.addText(pText, font(), text);
    }
    path.addRect(rect());
    painter.drawPath(path);
}

void TutoWidget::onClicked(int id)
{
    if(id == 0){
        if(currentIndex > 0)
            currentIndex--;
    }
    else if(id == 1){
        if(currentIndex < pages.count()-1)
            currentIndex++;
    }
    update();
    group->button(0)->setVisible(currentIndex!=0);
    group->button(1)->setVisible(currentIndex!=(pages.count()-1));
}
```

Example:

```
tuto = new TutoWidget(this); // this is the widget
tuto->addPage(QPoint(200, 200), 40, QPoint(100, 100), "some text1");
tuto->addPage(QPoint(300, 300), 60, QPoint(200, 100), "some text2");
tuto->addPage(QPoint(100, 200), 100, QPoint(200, 50), "some text3");
tuto->addPage(QPoint(200, 100), 80, QPoint(100, 200), "some text4");
```

[image]

[image]

The complete example is in the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/47660289)

Comment: Bad idea to add points as layout gui elements can change position. Better to use the approach I suggested and add the element pointer and map the coordinate to find the actual element position. The "return" presumably serves to close the tutorial rather than go to the previous page, so it should be present on the first page as well. Finally, a complete implementation will have to determine the text position in some more logical manner, depending on the xy position of the circle and the size of the window.

Comment: @dtech I understand your points, my intention was not to give a total solution, just give some samples of how to do it, those points I had already thought but I wanted to correct them later, just an approximation so that the author of the question has a starting point :P

Comment: And my point was that in that amount of code and effort you might as well have gone for a complete solution ;)

Comment: @dtech I did it in a short time, I just have a little free time, I will improve it. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing that will be of help to do this out of the box.

You can have an overlay widget that is normally hidden and only shows up during "tutorial" mode. You can easily punch a hole by using a `QPainterPath` to which you first add the rectangle of the entire widget and then add a circle where you want the hole, and then fill the resulting path.

You can get the absolute position of gui elements by mapping to the tutorial overlay widget.

I suggest you implement an abstract `Tutorial` class or at least a basic list of pointer/text pairs you implement for each widget you want to have a tutorial, then register each element of that widget in the tutorial - pointer to the gui element and the tutorial text. Then, when the tutorial for that widget is invoked, the overlay widget becomes visible and allows to iterate the particular elements of a widget that have information associated with them and redraw on iteration to show the circle and text.